copy multiple textareas with same button
I wrote this code to copy multiple textareas' content with a unique button, but only the first textarea is copied.


 var copyText = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0];
 function myFunction() {

     // Get the text field

     // Select the text field
     copyText.select();
     copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices

     // Copy the text inside the text field
     document.execCommand("copy");

     // Alert the copied text
     alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);

     ///second

 } 
<textarea class="form-control" tabindex="0">something</textarea>
 <button  onclick="myFunction()">clickme</button>
<textarea class="form-control"tabindex="3" >something1</textarea>
 <button  onclick="myFunction()">clickme</button>
<textarea class="form-control" >something2</textarea>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">clickme</button>



How can I resolve this issue so that multiple textareas are copied, instead?

The code shown is explicitly only ever copying the content of the first <textarea>.  Why are there three buttons that all do the same thing?  Do you want all three buttons to always copy all three contents all at once?  Do you want each button to copy only the content of the <textarea> immediately before it?  Something else?  Have you tried to implement your intended goal?

Pass the index of the textarea as a parameter to your myFunction, and put var copyText = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0]; inside the function, replacing the 0 with the value of the parameter.

I strongly suggest you delegate. Right now you only select the very first field on purpose
Here any click on a button with class="copy" in the container div will copy the textarea before it


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('button.copy'); // get the button
    if (!tgt) return // not a button

    // Select the text field    
    const field = tgt.previousElementSibling;
    field.select();
    field.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices
    // Copy the text inside the text field
    document.execCommand("copy");
    // Alert the copied text
    alert("Copied the text: " + field.value);
  });
});
<div id="container">
  <textarea class="form-control" tabindex="1">something 1</textarea>
  <button class="copy">clickme</button>
  <textarea class="form-control" tabindex="2">something 2</textarea>
  <button class="copy">clickme</button>
  <textarea class="form-control" tabindex="3">something 3</textarea>
  <button class="copy">clickme</button>
</div>



